# 27 people in groups of 3 so they are never with the same people after 13 rounds

Tags: permutations, combinations

I have a group of 27 students, and I want them to meet in groups of three in a sequence where each student is with each other student in a group exactly one time.

I know it should be possible. In 13 rounds, you meet 26 people. I need sequences, though, of which students are in groups together for each round.

I can't find a website that will do this for me. I have found several Round Robin tournament creators, but those produce results in pairs. I would like triads.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's actually impossible to do what you want. Though the reasoning that justifies that answer is a bit involved. I'll try and write up an answer here in a bit.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirkman%27s_schoolgirl_problem you can try constructing something similar to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1202892/is-there-a-memorable-solution-to-kirkmans-school-girl-problem

Comment: Looks like it is actually possible, and the solution corresponds with the Steiner system (2,3,6t+3) where in your case t=4.

Comment: See one such solution [at this site here](https://www.ccrwest.org/cover/t_pages/t2/k3/C_27_3_2.html).

Comment: Thank you all! I have a lot more information now. I didn't even know what to call it. That last link gave me exactly what I needed.